# Shorten syntax for nearly identical properties

Tags: c#, properties

I have to rework some code and stumbled upon a few classes which define a huge amount of very similar properties.

They look something like this:

```cs
public _ReturnType _PropertyName
{
    get
    {
        IMarkerInterface value = null;
        if (Properties != null) Properties.TryGetValue(_string, out value);
        return value as _ReturnType;
    }
    set { Properties[_string] = value; }
}
```

The only difference between them is the `_ReturnType`, the `_string` that is used in the dictionary `Properties` and obviously the `_PropertyName`.

I was wondering if there is a way to shorten the syntax?

Comment: use a code generation tool.

Comment: So you only wish to shorten the syntax or also (or mainly) reduce the code duplication?

Comment: Ask a question on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you see duplicate code, you extract a method. It would look something like this:

```
private T GetValueOrDefault<T>(string key)
{
    IMarkerInterface value = null;
    if (Properties != null) Properties.TryGetValue(key, out value);
    return value as T;
}
```

Then change your getter:

```
get
{
    return GetValueOrDefault<_ReturnType>("key");
}
```

But if this code is spread out over multiple classes, you'd have to define a base class containing the `Properties` property and the above `GetValueOrDefault()` method, albeit `protected` instead of `private`.

Alternatively, you'd define it as an extension method on whatever the type of `Properties` is:

```
public static T GetValueOrDefault<T>(this IDictionary<string, IMarkerInterface> properties, string key)
{
    IMarkerInterface value = null;
    if (properties != null) properties.TryGetValue(key, out value);
    return value as T;
}
```

And call it as such:

```
get
{
    return Properties.GetValueOrDefault<_ReturnType>("key");
}
```

But, as @Daniel comments, this smells like an ideal scenario for code generation, because without that you'd still have a couple of lines of (copy-pasted, error-prone) code.

There probably is a source somewhere for what these properties should be named, and you can use something like T4 templates to generate this code file from it.

Answer (score 0):

If `Properties` implements `IReadOnlyDictionary<string, object>` (like a `Dictionary<string, object>` for instance), one thing you could do is add an extension method:

```
public static TValue TryGetValue<TValue>(
    this IReadOnlyDictionary<string, object> properties,
    string key)
    where TValue : class
{
    if ((properties != null) &&
         properties.TryGetValue(key, out object value))
    {
        return value as TValue;
    }

    return null;
}
```

and then

```
public IMarkerInterface MarkerInterface
{
  get => Properties.TryGetValue<IMarkerInterface>("MarkerInterface");
  set { Properties["MarkerInterface"] = value; }
}
```

[Link to Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mUxyOk)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could do this:

```
private IMarkerInterface getIMF(string str) 
{
    IMarkerInterface value = null;
    Properties?.TryGetValue(_string, out value);
    return value;
}

public _ReturnType _PropertyName
    {
      get { return getIMF(_string) as _ReturnType; }
      set { Properties[_string] = value; }
    }
```